# Selecionar jogos da Lotofácil que contenham obrigatoriamente dezenas específicas

Tags: mysql, sql

Tenho um Banco de Dados MySQL contendo todas as combinações da Lotofácil, exemplificado abaixo:

[image: Tabela: lfv2]

Estou tentando recuperar, por exemplo, os jogos que contenham as dezenas 11, 17 e 21, obrigatoriamente no mesmo jogo.

Já tentei usar um:

```
SELECT * FROM lfv2
  WHERE Bol1 IN(11,17,21)
    AND Bol2 IN(11,17,21)
    AND Bol3 IN(11,17,21)
    AND Bol4 IN(11,17,21)
    AND Bol5 IN(11,17,21)
    AND Bol6 IN(11,17,21)
    AND Bol7 IN(11,17,21)
    AND Bol8 IN(11,17,21)
    AND Bol9 IN(11,17,21)
    AND Bol10 IN(11,17,21)
    AND Bol11 IN(11,17,21)
    AND Bol12 IN(11,17,21)
    AND Bol13 IN(11,17,21)
    AND Bol14 IN(11,17,21)
    AND Bol15 IN(11,17,21);
```

No entanto nada é retornado. Porém existem jogos que contém essas dezenas, como é o caso do jogo que ocupa a posição 3.268.760, dentre outros.
Existe alguma maneira do MySQL retornar essa consulta ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nesse caso você está afirmando que **todas as colunas do Bol1 a Bol15 tem que ter ou 11 ou 17 ou 21**. Você não irá conseguir solucionar esse problema dessa maneira.

Crie 3 colunas de validação (para cada numero) com o **CASE**, exemplo:

```
SELECT lf.* 
CASE 
   WHEN lf.bol1 = 11 THEN 'X'
   WHEN lf.bol2 = 11 THEN 'X'
   **... Aqui você faz o WHEN de todas colunas**

   ELSE '-' 
END validacao_1,
CASE 
   **...**
END validacao_2,
CASE 
   **...**
END validacao_3   
   
FROM lfv2 lf
```

Depois de criar os 3 **CASES** crie um **SUBSELECT** mais ou menos assim:

```
SELECT res.*
FROM (SELECT *)  res   **... Entre parentes o SELECT acima**
WHERE res.validação_1 = 'X'
AND res.validação_2 = 'X'
AND res.validação_3 = 'X'
```

Assim irá exibir o resultado que você deseja.